# Cast POST value to list using Ajax and Flask with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm building a list using JavaScript and the results look like this:

```
[['14', '15'], ['10']]
```

My Ajax call is doing a POST to a Flask service which is here:

```
@app.route('/search/results', methods = ['POST'])
def results():

    key = request.form['key']
    filters = request.form.get('filters', None)
```

I'm able to get the filters in the post, and when I do a print, I get the proper "string" results which looks exactly like it "should". However, I need to cast them to a list(). I'm relatively new to python, so perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way.

If I do the following:

```
if filters is not None:
    for f in filters:
        print f
```

I get this (simplified the results):

```
[
[
"
1
4
"
]
]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, all data sent over HTTP is just bytes, or strings of characters.

You'll need to use a format that can handle lists. JSON is such a format, and flask [supports that directly](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.json), provided you actually POST JSON data from your AJAX call:

```
key = request.json['key']
filters = requests.json.get('filters', [])
```

which assumes you posted the JavaScript structure:

```
{'key': 'somekey', 'filters': [['14', '15'], ['10']]}
```

Comment: Perfect, that got me going in the right direct. I did need to make sure I added contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" to my Ajax POST, and then just do a list(filters) in my code, and it worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't need to specify UTF-8 encoding for JSON in `Content-Type` header, it's the default.